# Facebook integration into Android Studio 0.2

Tags: gradle, android-studio, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to integrate facebook sdk into my android application. I followed every step specified in

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/

I know that google changed version of Gradle in Android Studio 0.2 (Gradle version to 0.5) , so i have changed the build.gradle file accordingly.

This is my updated gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

But after gradle compiled my project it finds errors.

I use this code in my onCreate method.

```
// start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything is fine till I press build and run button.

And this is the error log.

[image]

What am I missing?